How to get traefik to generate ssl cert after adding new service?
I'm running traefik as a reverse proxy and SSL endpoint. Running as a docker-compose service. Yesterday I added a new router and service to my traefik-config/traefik-dynamic.yaml. The new router is working; traffic is routed to my server correctly, so I know traefik found the new config without any other action from me. But it hasn't yet generated the associated SSL cert and I don't know how to make it do so. I'd prefer to avoid restarting it. I'm using acme and letsencrypt like this:
certificatesResolvers:
  myresolver:
    acme:
      email: me@example.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

Do I need to do something to "kick" it so it'll generate the cert? I've checked the docs but they don't say much about modifying configs while running.
Here's a redacted version of my traefik-config/traefik-dynamic.yaml. The newly added service is srv2:
http:
  routers:
    music:
      service: service-music
      rule: Host("music.example.com")
      tls:
        certresolver: myresolver
    rss:
      service: service-rss
      rule: Host("rss.example.com")
      tls:
        certresolver: myresolver
    srv2:
      service: service-srv2
      rule: Host("srv2.example.com")
      tls:
        certresolver: myresolver
    srv1:
      service: service-srv1
      rule: Host("srv1.example.com")
      tls:
        certresolver: myresolver
    srv3:
      service: service-srv3
      rule: Host("srv3.example.com")
      tls:
        certresolver: myresolver
  services:
    service-music:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://music.home.example.com:4040
    service-rss:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://home.example.com:8088
    service-srv1:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://home.example.com:8123
    service-srv3:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://home.example.com:3030
    service-srv2:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://home.example.com:8082


can you post the labels that you have set for your new service? have you set http.traefik.routers.<your-router>.tls.certresolver?

Yes, I used the same config for the new service "silverbullet" as I've had for my other services for a long time:
silverbullet.tls.certresolver: myresolver

Can you please post your traefik labels? We don't know what "the same config" looks like.

I just had to restart the whole thing. But I'll edit the post to include my config in case it helps others.
